# Moving Magento Search to Navigation Bar

Tags: magento, search, navigationbar

I know this issue has been asked several times around the web, but none of those solutions seem to work for me.

In the template `app/design/frontend/themename/default/template/page/html/header.phtml`

I have a call for `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('headernav') ?>`

In `headernav.phtml` lies the call for the search bar `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>`

Relevant contents of `app/design/frontend/themename/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml`:

```
<reference name="top.menu">
    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

This makes the search bar appear, but it is placed outside of the contents of `headernav.phtml`, and not inline where I put it. (I checked the markup in Chrome Dev Tools, it's nowhere near where it's supposed to be). I could hack it with CSS, or insert the contents of `form.mini.phtml` to be exactly where I want it, but I know this isn't the correct way to handle this, and will only lead to revisions later.

I have also tried:

```
<reference name="headernav">
    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Can anyone here enlighten me as to why this isn't appearing in the proper template file and how I can get xml to allow me to use it inside a "sub-template" of `header.phtml`

(e.g. `header.phtml` calls on `heavernav.phtml` which calls `form.mini.phtml`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theme **layout\catalogsearch.xml** change string

```
<reference name="header">
```

to

```
<reference name="catalog.topnav">
```

then put

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

in **catalog/navigation/top.phtml** where you want to see search block

Comment: wow @Sanketkumar Biswas your answer saved me from weeks of frustrationg having my topSearch disappearing with full page cache due to not having the reference name set to "catalog.topnav"- thank you SO MUCH!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Just tried to figure this out for the past few hours and got stuck until I seen Sanketkumar's answer.

Many other solutions will tell you to change the `<reference name="header">` to `<reference name="top.menu">`. I tried this many times and had the same error as you, with the navigation bar appearing right below the navigation bar.

I also tried removing the call of `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>` in my topmenu.phtml but it was still rendering somehow.

I made Sanketkumar's change and it worked properly.

My exact changes:

Use `local.xml` or create a new one and add this code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="catalog.topnav">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
        </reference>
   </default>
</layout>
```

Open topmenu.phtml and add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>` to the area you want to display. My exact section of the navigation looked like:

```html
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div id="menu-icon"><?php echo $this->__('Navigate') ?></div>
                <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
                    <?php echo $_menu ?>

           <li style="float: right;">
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('navSearch') ?>
     </li>

                </ul>
                <ul class="sf-menu-phone">
                    <?php echo $_menu ?>

           <li>
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('navSearch') ?>
     </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

(Notice that I added it twice - once for desktop and once for mobile site. I also added it in a list so it displayed properly and floated right on the desktop version.)

Hope this helps!